# How android avd size on disk less than actual size

Tags: android, windows, ntfs

[image: SizeOnDisk less than actual ize]

I am new to android studio, I created an AVD and the size on disk is showing less than the actual size. What I understood previously that size on disk is usually larger than file size. How ?

Comment: See: [What is the difference between size and size on disk?](https://superuser.com/q/66825/149731)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and could not find a decent explanation.

https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/136471-size-disk-means-what-onedrive-clarification.html

the #6 comment is most applicable in this case.

Basicly the the virtual images are not completely ocupied. So the free space can be compressed very efficiently. 20 or 40 GB qcow2 empty dynamic resizable image starts at 200k used for the general description. When the file gets data, the compression declines. When the image gets filled up it will get same size internally and on disk.
[image: Android image file screenshot]
In Android Studio you can check the userdata image files which are initially empty.(above screenshot)

It is like "100 empty 2 liter plastic bags can be put in 2 liter space and when they get filled, then they require more space. At the end more than 100*2 liter volume will be required, which is the cluster size influence zone".

Most of the internet search returns for the reverse question "size on disk larger than size" which is cluster size dependant.

p.s.Sorry. Do not have reputation to just leave a comment.